# Server - Client RSA keypair exchange

Tags: c++, c, rsa

I'm new to programming and i've got this little project going for my diploma and i need help on this little code. This is a Server->Client C++ code where server generates and sends RSA Keypair to client. My problem is that both server and client codes compiled without any problem but when i start it the client side doesn't get any keypair just blank.

Here is my server code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h> 

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define KEY_LENGTH  1024
#define PUB_EXP     3
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE

using std::exit;
#define int_error(msg) handle_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
void handle_error(const char* file, int lineno, const char* msg)
{
std::cerr << "\n** " << file << ":" << lineno << " " << msg << "\n";
ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
exit(-1);
}
void init_OpenSSL()
{
std::cout << "Initializng OpenSSL library ... ";
if (!SSL_library_init())
    int_error("OpenSSL initialization failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
SSL_load_error_strings();
}
DH* setup_dh()
{
DH* dh = DH_new();
if (!dh)
    int_error("DH_new failed");
std::cout << "Generating DH parameters ... ";
if (!DH_generate_parameters_ex(dh, 2, DH_GENERATOR_2, 0))
    int_error("DH_generate_parameters_ex failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Checking DH parameters ... ";
int codes = 0;
if (!DH_check(dh, &codes))
    int_error("DH_check failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Generating DH keys ... ";
if (!DH_generate_key(dh))
    int_error("DH_generate_key failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
return dh;
}
SSL_CTX* setup_ctx()
{
SSL_CTX* ctx;
std::cout << "Creating context ... ";
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_server_method());
if (!ctx)
    int_error("SSL_CTX_new failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
DH* dh = setup_dh();
std::cout << "Setting DH parameters ... ";
SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh(ctx, dh);    
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Setting cipher list ... ";
if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ADH-AES256-SHA") != 1)
    int_error("Error setting cipher list (no valid ciphers)");
std::cout << "done\n";
return ctx;
}
int main()
{
init_OpenSSL();
BIO *acc, *client;
SSL* ssl;
SSL_CTX* ctx;
ctx = setup_ctx();

size_t pri_len;        
size_t pub_len;            
char   *pri_key;           
char   *pub_key;

    std::cout << "Generating RSA (%d bits) keypair...\n", 1024;
RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(1024, 3, NULL, NULL);

BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, keypair);

pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);

pri_key = (char*)malloc(pri_len + 1);
pub_key = (char*)malloc(pub_len + 1);

BIO_read(pri, pri_key, pri_len);
BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);

pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';

std::cout << "Creating server socket ... ";
acc = BIO_new_accept("*:5055");
if (!acc)
    int_error("Error creating server socket");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Binding server socket ... ";
if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
    int_error("Error binding server socket");
std::cout << "done\n";
while (true) {
    std::cout << "Accepting connections ...\n";
    if (BIO_do_accept(acc) <= 0)
        int_error("Error accepting connection");
    client = BIO_pop(acc);
    std::cout << "Creating context ... ";
    if (!(ssl = SSL_new(ctx)))
        int_error("Error creating SSL context");
    std::cout << "done\n";
    SSL_set_bio(ssl, client, client);
    if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0)
        int_error("Error accepting SSL connection");
    std::cout << "SSL connection opened: " << SSL_get_cipher(ssl) << " " << 
    SSL_get_cipher_version(ssl) << " (" << SSL_get_cipher_bits(ssl, 0) << "      bits)\n";
    char buff[256] = {0};
    int r = SSL_read(ssl, buff, sizeof buff);   
    if (r > 0) {
        std::cout << buff;
        SSL_write(ssl, keypair, 1024 );
    }
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    std::cout << "SSL connection finished\n";
}
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
BIO_free(acc);
std::cout << "Server closed\n";
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
using namespace std;
using std::exit;

#define int_error(msg) handle_error(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
void handle_error(const char* file, int lineno, const char* msg)
{
std::cerr << "** " << file << ":" << lineno << " " << msg << "\n";
ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
exit(-1);
}
void init_OpenSSL()
{
std::cout << "Initializng OpenSSL library ... ";
if (!SSL_library_init())
    int_error("OpenSSL initialization failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
SSL_load_error_strings();
}
SSL_CTX* setup_ctx()
{
SSL_CTX* ctx;
std::cout << "Creating context ... ";
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
if (!ctx)
    int_error("SSL_CTX_new failed");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Setting cipher list ... ";
if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ADH-AES256-SHA") != 1)
    int_error("Error setting cipher list (no valid ciphers)");
std::cout << "done\n";
return ctx;
}
int main()
{
init_OpenSSL();
BIO* conn;
SSL* ssl;
SSL_CTX* ctx;
ofstream myfile;
ctx = setup_ctx();
std::cout << "Creating connection ... ";
conn = BIO_new_connect("192.168.1.10:5055");
if (!conn)
    int_error("Error creating connection");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Connecting to server ... ";
if (BIO_do_connect(conn) <= 0)
    int_error("Error connecting to server");
std::cout << "done\n";
std::cout << "Creating context ... ";
if (!(ssl = SSL_new(ctx)))
    int_error("Error creating an SSL context");
std::cout << "done\n";
SSL_set_bio(ssl, conn, conn);
std::cout << "Opening connection ... ";
if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0)
    int_error("Error connecting SSL object");
std::cout << "done\n";
SSL_write(ssl, "The client is connected", 26);
char buff[64] = {0};
int bread = SSL_read(ssl, buff, sizeof buff);
if (bread > 0)
    std::cout << "The key has been recieved\n";
      myfile.open ("keypair.pem");
      myfile << buff;
      myfile.close();
SSL_shutdown(ssl);
SSL_free(ssl);
std::cout << "SSL connection finished\n";
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
std::cout << "Client finished\n";
}
```

Can someone show me what i did wrong and it would be great if someone can tell me how i can get my private key and public keys(server generated) separately. Thanks a lot guys...really appreciate it

Comment: Why would one host disclose a private key to another host?

Comment: Well my entire program is that there is 1 server and 4 client programs on every client there is a multicast sender and 3 receiver programs every client receives pub and pri keys from server(secure) then multicast program uses this keypairs to encrypt and decrypt their messages...well something like that hehehehe...

Comment: It's a strange design. It violates every precept of PKI. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Yes pls. After this completes i'm trying to add server<->client authentication with certificate... i can't find where i did wrong here everything compiles fine then when i open the file in client folder there is nothing(file where should be public key and private key) and i don't know how to save public key and private key separately for encryption...pls help me...